# Else Box keeps activating but the If solutions are satisfied

Tags: vba

```
Private Sub Dutybox_Change()
Dim Val As String

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("User Dashboard").Range("L17").Value = Me.Dutybox.Value

 Calculate
 
If Me.ComboBox18.RowSource <> "" And Me.RankCombo.Value <> "" And Me.Exambox.Value <> "" And Me.Dutybox.Value <> "" Then
Me.ComboBox18.RowSource = "=Rate"
Else
MsgBox "Please Select all the above values"

End If

End Sub
```

So the IF parts are all filled, and it should fill ComboBox18 with =Rate (a named range) but it keeps popping up the Msgbox
Item 1

```
Private Sub ComboBox18_Change()
Dim Val As String

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("User Dashboard").Range("L18").Value = Me.ComboBox18.Value

End Sub
```

Item 2

```
Private Sub RankCombo_Change()

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("User Dashboard").Range("L15").Value = Me.RankCombo.Value
 
End Sub
```

Item 3

```
Private Sub Exambox_Change()
Dim Val As String

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("User Dashboard").Range("L16").Value = Me.Exambox.Value

End Sub
```

Code to push range to ComboBox18

```
Private Sub ComboBox18_Intialize()
    MsgBox "combo box"
    Me.ComboBox18.List = Application.Transpose(Names("Rate").RefersToRange.Value)

End Sub
```

I can't figure out why Msgbox is populating when the values are satisified.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

One way to debug this program is to verify the output in Immediate window,

Please [break](https://www.excelanytime.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=349) your code at

```
If Me.ComboBox18.RowSource <> "" And Me.RankCombo.Value <> "" And Me.Exambox.Value <> "" And Me.Dutybox.Value <> "" Then
```

On immediate window type the following and press enter to verify the conditions

```
?Me.ComboBox18.RowSource <> ""
?Me.RankCombo.Value <> ""
?Me.Exambox.Value <> ""
?Me.Dutybox.Value <> ""
```

all the above four condition should return true.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your expressions might not properly handle `Null` values.
Try using `Nz()` like this: `Nz(Me.RankCombo.Value,"") <> ""`

You can also add code to check your assessments:

```
Debug.Print "Combo18", Me.ComboBox18.RowSource <> ""
Debug.Print "Rank", Me.RankCombo.Value <> ""
```